# Visualize the verification conditions in Dafny

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

We are doing some academic experiments in Dafny and were wondering if there is a way to see the generated verification conditions in Dafny?

We searched the literature, websites and blogs but did not find any reference...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  One way is like this:

```
 dafny verify --solver-option VERBOSITY=2 file.dfy
```

A more useful way is to generate the SMTLIB file passed into the theorem prover like this:

```
 dafny verify --solver-option LOG_FILE=output.smt2 file.dfy
```

Finally, you can also generate the intermediate Boogie file like this as well:

```
 dafny verify --bprint file.bpl file.dfy
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However, this is not really something we want: we would like to visualize/see the verification conditions as logical formulae. For example, if I have a loop invariant, what are the conditions to be proved. Or can we visualize smth as explained with the commands you suggested but it is not straightforward? Thank you!

Comment: Well the `smt2` output contains the verification conditions expressed as logical formulae.  However, it doesn't map them _back_ to specific language level constructs.  Boogie is more helpful in this regard, as it is closer to the original Dafny language.  For example, loop invariants in Dafny should become loop invariants in Boogie.  But, the process is not straightforward.